# How do you get values of a variable inside a model call

Tags: r

When making an arima model by passing variables instead of hard coding them, the call inside the model will show the variable name and not the values passed.

Is it possible to have it pass the information inside the variable to the call? If so how would i do it?
i.e in the following code:

```
library(forecast)

order <- c(1,1,2)
# output i get:
arima(gold, order = order)$call

# output i would like
arima(x = gold, order = c(1,1,2))$call
```

The first output would be `arima(gold, order = order)`, the second, `arima(x = gold, order = c(1,1,2))`. Would it be possible to get output 2 from call 1?

Comment: What is your problem: 1) How to get `arima` to actually use the values in `order`, or 2) get `arima` to print the values of `order` when looking at the `call`?

Comment: I would like to get arima to store them in to model$call$order appropriately so that other functions can interact with the model. Printing them would be a bonus